Is there any way to add checkbox inside of wxPropertyGrid
I'm working on a wxWidgets application and trying to add a checkbox to a wxPropertyGrid. I attempted to use wxBoolProperty, but this property appears as a dropdown (combo box) instead of a checkbox.
What I want is for the user to be able to check or uncheck a checkbox, with the state correctly reflecting (true or false). However, in my current implementation, when I add a wxBoolProperty, I end up with a dropdown view.
I'm using the following code:
pg->Append(new wxBoolProperty(name, name, std::get<bool>(value.value)));

And thats what I am getting:

How can I correctly add a checkbox to wxPropertyGrid?
Like this example:

I'm using wxWidgets version: 3.2.6.

Found a solution. Instead of creating like this:
wxPropertyGrid* pg = new wxPropertyGrid(panel, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxPG_DEFAULT_STYLE | wxPG_SPLITTER_AUTO_CENTER);

pg->Append(new wxBoolProperty(name, name, std::get<bool>(value.value)));

We have to create something like this:
wxPGProperty* boolProperty = new wxBoolProperty(name, name, std::get<bool>(value.value));
boolProperty->SetEditor(new wxPGCheckBoxEditor);
pg->Append(boolProperty);

Adding that line solves the problem:
boolProperty->SetEditor(new wxPGCheckBoxEditor);

